# how to reverse parse from control datasource in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a dropdown control in form lets say it as dropdown1

on button click i need full row of binded table to row

```
page_load()
{
   dropdown1.DataSource = datatable1;
}
dropdown1_selectedIndexChange()
{
   DataRow dRow1 = datatable1. row of selectedValue //Corresponding row of selected item with out calling select again to database
}
```

tried google a lot but did not found any suitable solution

Comment: currently i am calling database select with dropdown1.selectedValue i need to less call database to reduce load on database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following coding it's worked. 
Use `Select` method of data table for filtering row

```
    public static DataTable dt = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            // This is my data source
            dt= TagController.TagSelect(-1, -1, "", "").Tables[0];
            ddlQuestions.DataSource = dt;
            ddlQuestions.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlQuestions.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlQuestions.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlQuestions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Select("Id=" + ddlQuestions.SelectedValue)[0];
        Response.Write(dr["Description"].ToString());            
    }
```

Comment: This Solution Worked.
But From Some friend I Got Another too

DataTable dt = (DataTable) ddlQuestions.DataSource;

But this isn't Working